# Built kernel won't boot, missing AHCI driver?

Tags: boot, drivers, kernel, compiling

I need to apply a kernel patch and so I set about building a kernel. First I fetched the source and build dependencies with

```
# apt-get source linux-image-`uname -r`
# apt-get build-dep linux-image-`uname -r`
```

Entering the source directory I applied my patch, and then grabbed the current kernel config and performed the build with

```
# cp -vi /boot/config-`uname -r` .config
# make-kpkg --initrd --append-to-version=-test kernel-image kernel-headers
```

Finally I installed the newly built kernel from the DEBs created in ../

```
# dpkg -i linux-image-3.13.11.4-test_3.13.11.4-test-10.00.Custom_i386.deb
# dpkg -i linux-headers-3.13.11.4-test_3.13.11.4-test-10.00.Custom_i386.deb
```

When rebooting I found my kernel in the Grub menu, but trying to boot it I ended up with

```
Gave up waiting for root device
...
ALERT! /dev/disk/by-uuid/[my-correct-disk-uuid-here] does not exist.
```

At the resulting BusyBox prompt I've tried looking in /dev/ and there are no disk drives present, which seems to indicate that the kernel module for my disk controller has not been loaded (it isn't in /proc/modules). How can this be though, when I've used the same kernel version that I'm running as I type this - and **with the same config**? Building kernels is not something I do on a daily basis, nor for pleasure, so I would appreciate any help with this.

**Edit:** I should add that I've tried using the /dev/sd** syntax for `root=` in the Grub command line, with the same result. So it's not that the UUID lookup fails; the disk controller doesn't even exist. In case it's relevant, the machine is a Thinkpad X32 with Intel's 855PM chipset (PATA HDD).

Comment: Did the .deb packages run update-grub and initramfs like they were supposed to?

Comment: I believe so; update-grub was definitely run as the boot menu includes the new kernel. I am a little confused about initramfs and initrd but I believe that supplying the `--initrd` argument to `make-kpkg` takes care of this?

Comment: Boot a working kernel and check in `dmesg` which module detects the drive. Then check your .config and make sure that module is being built, and unpack the initramfs file and check that the module is present there. Try building an uncustomised kernel without your patch, and using `dpkg-buildpackage`, to confirm that the problem really is with your customised kernel and not something else.

Comment: By the way, for compiling on old hardware it takes a long time to build a full Ubuntu kernel, you can speed this up quite a bit by running `make localmodconfig` and/or using [modprobedb-db](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Modprobed-db) from a cron job to build a list of all of your required dynamically loaded kernel modules over time.

Answer (score 1):

Now, because of the UUID error I feel it is necessary to verify the information in /etc/fstab because this is where the file system information (UUID) is mounted from.

First, boot into an older kernel or a live-disk session.

Execute the following command to find the UUID for your root partition.

```
sudo blkid -o list
```

The output should be similar to this example:

```
/dev/sda1      ext4     home      /                 bac7229a-e019-5679-931d-5e14f15ff4bc 
/dev/sda2      ntfs     c         (not mounted)     40Ajghyr-65uB-EA5C-7y8y9t6g54j5
/dev/sda3      ext4               (not mounted)     640565a9-310b-5d6r-8d8v7-e887do893f80
/dev/sda5      ext4               (not mounted)     e777547b-3a3a-7tgd-9a12-2769wsrbd92
/dev/sda6      swap               <swap>            d72b694e-4976-3333-hso5-7894e6s9d2
```

Now, use 'nano', 'vi', 'gedit', 'mousepad' or whatever your favorite text editor is to edit or confirm the listed UUID for your root partition in /etc/fstab. For this example, I'll use nano:

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

Now, according our information, our /etc/fstab information should look something like this assuming you are using a non-encrypted, single partition setup mounted at " / " :

```
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=bac7229a-e019-5679-931d-5e14f15ff4bc /         ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=d72b694e-4976-3333-hso5-7894e6s9d2 none        swap    sw              0       0
```

If the information in /etc/fstab was incorrect and you have updated this information accordingly, **all you need to do now is reboot** because /etc/fstab is loaded post grub and is not directly associated with the configuration of of your initrd.img.

(The system will read the information in /etc/fstab and will automatically load the correct partitions from there)

---

If this does not fix your problem or if the information in /etc/fstab is accurate, you may need to run:

```
sudo update-initramfs -v -c -k all
```

**You may want to substitute "all" with a specific kernel version** if you do not want to update all of the existing initrd images ( this way you can update just the image that will not boot ). See here for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9645073/how-to-make-an-initrd-img-in-ubuntu

If all goes well, don't forget to run:

```
sudo update-grub2
```

before you reboot.

Please post any errors.

Comment: The update-initramfs fixed my problem. Thanks!